# pandas to match columns names based on a list object based check

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to match a list object with pandas DataFrame, i've a condition here where the list object which contains the column names so, sometimes the DataFrame may contains the all names which are in `matchObj` but times when the DataFrame will only have few column names only in that situation it fails to do the Job.

below is my example lists `matchObj` and `matchObj1` for example:

```
>>> matchObj = ['equity01',  'equity02',  'equity1'  'equity2']
>>> matchObj1 = ['equity01',  'equity02']
```

Below is the DataFrame:

```
>>> df
   equity01  equity02  equity03  equity04  equity05
0         1         4         7         2         5
1         2         5         8         3         6
2         3         6         9         4         7
```

While i'm using the list `matchobj1` against df it works as it founds the column names.

```
>>> print(df[matchObj1])
   equity01  equity02
0         1         4
1         2         5
2         3         6
```

However, it fails to work with `matchobj` because df doest not contain the `equity1 equity2` thus throws the `KeyError: "['equity1equity2'] not in index"`

```
>>> print(df[matchObj])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2133, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2177, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1269, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['equity1equity2'] not in index"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use -

```
print(df[[i for i in matchObj if i in df.columns]])
```

**Output**

```
   equity01  equity02
0         1         4
1         2         5
2         3         6
```

**Explanation**

`[i for i in matchObj if i in df.columns]` only fetches columns that are present in `df`. Ignores all the rest. Hope that helps.