# How can I know the type of values in column names and list?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tyring to select columns that whose column names is matched to the value in the list (or array).
For example, there are toy example of dataframe and list as below:

```py
import pandas as pd

data={'3123':[1,2,3], 
'5342':[3,2,4], 
'2039':[8,3,6], 
'1398':[2,8,8], 
'9854':[6,2,1], 
'8834':[3,7,0]
}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df 
#   3123    5342    2039    1398    9854    8834
#0     1       3       8       2       6       3
#1     2       2       3       8       2       7
#2     3       4       6       8       1       0
```

```py
list1= ['3123', '5342', '8834']
```

I expect the result like this:

```py
#   3123    5342    8834
#0     1       3       3
#1     2       2       7
#2     3       4       0
```

By referencing [pandas to match columns names based on a list object based check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026428/pandas-to-match-columns-names-based-on-a-list-object-based-check) , I runned the code and get a expected result.

```py
print(exx[[i for i in list1 if i in exx.columns]])
```

In this case, I set the column names and value of list to str manually(i.e., '3123', ... '8834') and know the type of values.
But the above code didn't work when I open the .csv file and get dataframe from .csv. (It returns the empty dataframe while there are same value between column name and value in the list)
I guess it is due to the mismatch of types between column names and values in list.
How can I know the type of them and make same?

Comment: why not just `df[list1]`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal  Thank you for your comment. I tried your suggestion, but it returns error "KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([  3479,    472,   2475,   2965,   4193,   1069,   2067,   3012,\n              1791,   1019,\n            ...\n             65059, 164714,   7156,   9440,  84240,  29889,  83549,   7301,\n             65266,  51231],\n           dtype='int64', length=3452)] are in the [columns]"....

Comment: @Ssong - Is possible values in list are integers? How working `exx[exx.columns.intersection([str(i) for i in list1])]` ?

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for your suggestion. The code that you give me works well in both toy example and my original dataset. As I mentioned in the original question, exx and list1 is toy examples for validating the code `print(exx[[i for i in list1 if i in exx.columns]])` .  I recognize that my data is nparray, not list. Sorry for the confusion. Again, thank you for your code!